# Return 1 value based on unique criteria

Tags: excel

We have the data below:

```
Database   Scenario 2.    Other Column

1.                   Q1
1.                   C1
1.                   Blank
2.                   Q1          
2.                   C1
```

I'd like a 1 value returned in the other column, if both Q1 and C1 appear for the same Database, so column 1, 2, 4, 5 would return a 1 value, row 3 would return a 0 value.

Thanks

Comment: Both Q1 and C1 appear for database 1. What's wrong with row 3?

Comment: Excellent. Thank yiu

Comment: If my answer worked for you please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 1):

This will test whether the two exists in the same database and that the value in B is one of the two strings to search:

```
=IF(AND(SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,{"Q1","C1"}))>=2,OR(B2="Q1",B2="C1")),1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Remember that if this answers the question to mark it correct when able, after a few minutes.  Please click the check mark by the answer.  It is available 15 minutes or so after the question has been asked.

Comment: I assume if i want to add another level in, for example "D1", I'd change the code to. =IF(AND(SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,{"Q1","C1", "D1"}))>=2,OR(B2="Q1",B2="C1",B2="D1")),1,0)

Comment: @user3103022 no sorry, change the `>=2` to `>=3`.  Again remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Just realised this doesn't actually work, for example it returns a 1 when there is a Q1 and a database, it must only return a 1 when there is a Q1 and C1 in the same database